# How to Remove Old Email Accounts

Tags: settings, sync, email, accounts

So I just bought a new phone last week and I'm in the process of downloading all my apps and setting it up. I was trying to log into the Slack app when this pop-up appeared with a list of all the emails that I've ever used.

Half of them were old email accounts that I haven't used in a while and they ranged from Gmail to Yahoo to Outlook and even my old college email address showed up. Where are these emails stored and how can I remove them from my device?

I've wrecked my brain and could not figure this out. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Most likely Slack has stored them and they are connected to your phone number. Check your Slack account.

Comment: Hmm, I can't see how it could be tied to my Slack account since I only started using Slack last year. Some of the email addresses on that list are from 5 years ago. My phone number is also not tied to Slack.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshots, it looks like old logins saved in Chrome. If you've used Chrome to remember your login details for websites, that's what they'll be. They're synced across desktop as well as mobile Chrome installs via your Google account. The UI for selecting which login to use has changed recently, so it's natural that you might be surprised by it.

You can delete old login details from the Chrome settings, on PC or mobile. On Android, the steps are:

1. In Chrome, click the three dots button in the top-right
2. Choose **Settings** from the menu
3. Choose **Passwords**
4. Either turn off **Save passwords** to disable the feature entirely, or:

   1. Click a site in the list
   2. Click the bin/trashcan icon in the top-right to delete that password
   3. Repeat that for all the old login details you want removed

Comment: You are a genius! I'm not logged into Chrome on my phone but I did go to Passwords Manager in my Google account and found the list of saved emails and passwords. Erased everything and viola!